# Excel array formula anomaly

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have an array formula in Excel that works fine in all cells of the array *except* when there is a change in the conditional tests, and I'm not sure why.
The array formula is:

```
{=TEXT(VALUE(Header!$A$2)+VALUE(ReadingID)
*(IF(EventID="2", 1,IF(EventID="4", 1,0))*(VALUE(Header!$N$2)/86400)
+IF(EventID="2", 0, IF(EventID="4", 0, 1))*(VALUE(Header!$M$2)/86400))
, "#.000000")}
```

Typical data for the formula cells value:

- **Header!$A$2** = '43432.40434' # An excel serial date/time number as text.
- **ReadingID** = #incremental numbers as text e.g. '1000', '1001' etc.
- **EventID** = # Values 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 as text.
- **Header!$M$2** = 60 # as text.
- **Header!$N$2** = 10 # as text.

The **ReadingID** and **EventID** columns are the same size as the array formula column. 
Typical results when **EventID** changes from, say, "2" to "3", are as follows:

```
ReadingID EventID  Result        Diff
  '1540     '2     43432.582581  0.000116
  '1541     '2     43432.582696  0.000115
  '1542     '3     43433.475173  0.892477
  '1543     '3     43433.475868  0.000695
  '1544     '3     43433.476562  0.000694
```

The **Diff** column is simply to show the increment from row to row and is consistent either side of the transition in **EventID** value (e.g. from "2" to "3"). The same anomaly occurs at all points where the **EventID** value changes (i.e. "1" to "2"; "3" to "4").

The array formula spans several thousand cells and returns the expected result in all other rows, *except* when **EventID** changes.

I originally tried an `OR` function to perform the incremental sum, but that didn't work, hence the nested `IF` statements.

Can anyone suggest if there is something wrong with the array formula, or how to avoid this rogue result?

**NOTE:** *The data is in text format as it is being imported from elsewhere in CSV format and I would like to preserve the raw import.*

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what is happening. Is there any way you can share a picture of your actual results and your expected results? Additionally, I think you can implement your `OR` function as follows: `{=TEXT(VALUE($A$2)+VALUE(ReadingID)*(IF(OR(EventID="2",EventID="4"),1,0)*(VALUE(Header!$N$2)/86400)+IF(OR(EventID="2",EventID="4"),0,1)*(VALUE(Header!$M$2)/86400)),"#.000000")}`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're identifying as an anomaly. It seems like the significant change in Diff at the EventID transition would be expected given that Header!$N$2 and Header!$M$2 are different values.

Comment: @TotsieMae Basically the results should be the same increment (Diff) at each respective EventID, +/- rouinding errors. So EventID="2" results should all be 0.00016 and ALL EventID="3" steps should be 0.000695. The anomaly is the rogue value at the first transition, i.e, 0.892477 shown is random and all other transitions are equally random values. When I tried the OR function it didn't return the state for each step, it seems to return for the whole array. Sorry for poor style, edit guidelines are not clear.

Comment: @StoneGiant After parking this for a couple of days, I finally had the 'light bulb' moment you were clearly trying to point out to me. No anomaly, just wrong formula on my part for the task in hand DOH! Thank you.

Comment: We all sometimes get buried in what we are doing and can't see what's right in front of our eyes. Glad you got it figured out.